# I keep getting this 403 Forbidden: "error code: 1010" on my spring boot api call with restTemplate. Can someone help me clear this error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Country.java This class is used to collect and populate the response.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Country {
    private String name;

    private double iso_code;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\nIso Code: " + iso_code;
    }
}
```

CountryRestClient.java: I checked the api key to make sure that I do not get forbidden error but it did not work.

```
@Component
public class CountryRestClient {

    private static final String url = "https://vaccovid-coronavirus-vaccine-and-treatment-tracker.p.rapidapi.com/api/npm-covid-data/countries-name-ordered";


    private static final String apiKeyName = "X-RapidAPI-Key";

    private static final String apiKeyValue = "42f0727d22msh9d";

    private static final String hostName = "X-RapidAPI-Host";

    private static final String hostValue = "vaccovid-coronavirus-vaccine-and-treatment-tracker.p.rapidapi.com";

    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public CountryRestClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {

        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }


    public Country getCountry() {
        Country country = null;
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(url);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(apiKeyName, apiKeyValue);
            headers.set(hostName, hostValue);

            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            ResponseEntity<Country[]> countryEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Country[].class);

            country = countryEntity.getBody()[0];

            System.out.println("Name:" + country.getName() + "\nISO: " + country.getIso_code());

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return country;
    }
}
```

CountryController.java: I also made this controller to expose the endpoints.

```
@RestController
public class CountryController {

    @GetMapping("/countries")
    public Country getCountries() {
        return new CountryRestClient(new RestTemplateBuilder()).getCountry();
    }

}
```

The error that I get is: The error that I get is: The error that I get is: The error that I get is: The error that I get is: The error that I get is: The error that I get is:
The error that I get is:

```
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 08 23:10:25 EDT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
403 Forbidden: "error code: 1010"
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: "error code: 1010"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at com.thymeleafdemo.client.CountryRestClient.getCountries(CountryRestClient.java:49)
    at com.thymeleafdemo.controller.CountryController.getCountries(CountryController.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same thing , I tried the solution suggested by @Vivek_bats and it worked for me but we don't need to include all the header , we just need the User agent header and value can be application like this

```
headers.set("User-Agent", "Application");
```

Refer to this [post](https://www.theprogrammerguide.com/spring/consume_rest_api/#:%7E:text=403%20Forbidden%3A%20%5Berror%20code%3A%201010%5D%3A%20If%20you%20didn%E2%80%99t%20add%20user%20agent%20in%20header%20you%20may%20get%20this%20403%20error.)

Comment: You might consider to make your answer more "standalone". It is OK to mention another answer, but your answer should be understandable on its own, with the reference to the other answer just as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to call another system via an exposed API. It was working on SOAP UI and postman but was failing to call from the actual server. I had to put these additional headers to make it work:

Accept : `*/*`

User-Agent : PostmanRuntime/7.28.4

Connection : keep-alive

Cache-Control : no-cache

Please let me know if you found any other way to fix it. As far as I can understand the issue arises due to some missing headers

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cloudflare certificate in your application, disable cloud orange and test.  don't worry about API side certificate.  I believe it will resolve.

Comment: I don't think OP said they are using Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on spring-security version 2.2.13.RELEASE. This also applies on spring-boot version 3 and below.

My keycloak server was proxied through Cloud Flare orange cloud, when spring-security tried to fetch jwk-set-uri it was throwing "HttpStatus 403, error 1010, Failed to to fetch jwk-set-uri"

I resolved this error by disabling [browser integrity check](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/tools/browser-integrity-check/#:%7E:text=Log%20into%20the%20Cloudflare%20dashboard,switch%20the%20toggle%20to%20Off).